# Thermal Properties of the Free Electron Gas: Explanation of the $N$-particle systems and averaging over all $N$-particle stationary states

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

I have a master's degree in engineering and am trying to study more detailed topics in solid-state physics on my own.
I have difficulties to understand the (2.38)

$$P_{N}(E)=\cfrac{e^{-E/K_{B}T}}{\sum e^{-E_{\alpha}^{N}/K_{B}T}}$$

in Ashcroft Mermin Solid State Physics (section Thermal Properties of the Free Electron Gas: The Fermi Dirac Distribution).
Where

$$E_{\alpha}^{N}$$

is the energy of the $\alpha^{th}$ stationary state of the N-electron system, the sum being over all such states.

$P_{N}(E)$
is a (probability?) weight.

As stated in the text (which, however, lacks a bibliographical section with the reference texts consulted) this formula comes from some basic principles of statistical mechanics

Unfortunately, I did not take a course in statistical mechanics but only the basic physics courses (Physics I: Mechanics and Thermodynamics, Physics II: Electromagnetism and Waves and Introduction to Probability and Statistics ).

So I am interested to understand what basic concepts this formula comes from.
Can you point me to a statistical mechanics course or section (better if free of access) that explains how to derive this formula?
Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: It's the Boltzmann factor that states the relative frequency of a state is $\exp(-E/kT)$ where $E$ is the energy of the state.  The sum in the denominator is called the partition function and is there to normalize the probablity measure over states to $1$.

Comment: If I was to pick a single expression that I expect to be derived in *every* book or course on statistical mechanics, it would be this one.

Comment: This may help - [The Boltzmann factor: A simplified derivation](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=138377&token=ce78f1a73be3528669c0a5a4a6675d0e3284b02e)

Comment: thank you for helping. I have now clear idea where to find these information.